Air filters in optics lab
I am working in an optics lab and we have a lot of dust in the air, which ofcourse is not healthy for optical elements. I wonder if anybody has solved this problem by installing air filters, if they are effective and which ones would you recommend? We have a laminar flow optical table with HEPA filters, but not all of them.
